# How to reduce the height of a DataGridCell in Silverlight?

Tags: silverlight, datagrid

There is "a lot of" space above and below the text lines in a Silverlight `DataGrid`.

The default `DataGridCell` instance that is generated by `DataGridTextColumn` renders a `TextBlock` with a *Margin* of 4 (worked out using [Silverlight Spy](http://firstfloorsoftware.com/silverlightspy)).

I tried to create a custom `DataGridCell` template and set the *Margin* and *Padding* values to zero there, but neither this nor setting a `ContentTemplate` changed anything.

Do you have any idea how I can reduce the height of certain `DataGridCell`'s to a value next to 0?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found the answer by myself:

The problem is the part of the `DataGridTextColumn` class where the TextBlock that is placed inside each cell generated:

```
 protected override FrameworkElement GenerateElement(DataGridCell cell, object dataItem)
    {
        TextBlock block = new TextBlock {
            Margin = new Thickness(4.0),
            VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center
        };
        if (DependencyProperty.UnsetValue != base.ReadLocalValue(FontFamilyProperty))
        {
            block.FontFamily = this.FontFamily;
        }
        if (this._fontSize.HasValue)
        {
            block.FontSize = this._fontSize.Value;
        }
        if (this._fontStyle.HasValue)
        {
            block.FontStyle = this._fontStyle.Value;
        }
        if (this._fontWeight.HasValue)
        {
            block.FontWeight = this._fontWeight.Value;
        }
        if (this._foreground != null)
        {
            block.Foreground = this._foreground;
        }
        if ((this.Binding != null) || !DesignerProperties.IsInDesignTool)
        {
            block.SetBinding(TextBlock.TextProperty, this.Binding);
        }
        return block;
    }
```

As you can see the Margin is statically set to 4.0. To get around this I created a wrapper class that derived from `DataGridTextColumn`:

```
public class DataGridCustomTextColumn : DataGridTextColumn
    {
        protected override FrameworkElement GenerateElement(DataGridCell cell, object dataItem)
        {
            //Get the parent TextBlock
            TextBlock block = (TextBlock)base.GenerateElement(cell, dataItem);

            if (ElementStyle != null) //if an element style is given
            {
                //Apply each setter of the style to the generated block
                ElementStyle.Setters.OfType<System.Windows.Setter>()
                    .ForEach((setter) => block.SetValue(setter.Property, setter.Value));
            }
            //Return styled block
            return (FrameworkElement)objBlock;
        }
    }
```